# How might I resolve MappingExceptions after upgrading from hibernate 4.3.11.Final to 5.4.3.Final?

Tags: hibernate, migration, hibernate-mapping

I have a rather large project that has been using hibernate 4.3.11.Final with no issues. I upgraded to **hibernate 5.4.3.Final** and now I am getting several MappingException errors when launching my application. Below is what the errors look like:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: property [testname] not found on entity [path.to.my.pojo.object]
```

I know that's not a lot of detail but I am hoping someone will recognize this as a common issue they've seen when upgrading from hibernate 4 to 5. I can't figure out if this is an issue with the hibernate annotations or maybe something with the sessionFactoy has changed? But those errors I get are not very helpful. I have checked the migration guides for help but haven't seen anything obvious. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem while migrating from Hibernate 4 to 5.

The problem (for me at least) was the usage of a deprecated @Index annotation in the entity which holds a collection of [path.to.my.pojo.object].

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "contactId", nullable = false)
@Filter(name = FilterConstants.SOMEFILTER)
@Index(name = "SOME_IDX") // <= deprecated
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<TestDBO> tests = new ArrayList<TestDBO>();
```

Removing the @Index annotation made the Exception go away.

The index should probably be added again by using @Table(indexes = ...) (which i haven't done yet)